# ¿Cómo solucionar errores en Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

como puedo solucionar esto, soy principiante de Reactjs. Al querer crear un nuevo proyecto me marca estos errores. Alguna solución, de antemano gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon los errores _como texto, con formato_. No todos podemos visualizar las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

¿podrías ejecutar estos comandos en órden? Me parece que se te olvidó el `npm init`

```
npm init
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app postales
```

En caso de no funcionarte, sigue la guía de este enlace, quizás te funcione: https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-a-react-app-on-windows-10/